# Problems with extracting a watermark

Tags: image, matlab, watermark, svd

I'm working on watermarking and recently I try to developp the method found [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com.sci-hub.org/science/article/pii/S0030402614000345) for a blind color watermarking. For embedding the watermark every is Ok I got great results but in extraction part I don't know why I have a black watermark image and it doesn't look like the original one!! Here is the code I use for extraction:

```
function extracted_mark=extract_dyn_U(rgb_wateramrked,ix,iy);
%  rgb_wateramrked=imread('Watermarked_rgbImage.jpg');      %%% read original image
img=rgb2ycbcr(rgb_wateramrked);        %%%convert to ycbcr color space
imgy=img(:,:,1);
imgcb=img(:,:,2);
imgcr=img(:,:,3);
[ca1,ch1,cv1,cd1]=dwt2(imgy,'haar');        %%% Apply dwt 2level on ca
[ca2,ch2,cv2,cd2]=dwt2(ca1,'haar');
[m n]=size(ca2);
blocksize=m/32
 %********************Extraction**********************
 watermark1=zeros(32,32);  % define a zero matrix with the original watermak    size
 for k=1:32
    for j=1:32
       L=zeros(4,4);
        L=ca2(ix:ix+blocksize-1,iy:iy+blocksize-1);
       [U,S,V]=svd(L);
        if abs(U(2,1))>= abs(U(3,1))
       watermark1(k,j)=1;
        else
       watermark1(k,j)=0;
        end
    end
end
  imshow(watermark1);
 extracted_mark=watermark1;
 end
end
```

It just doesn't give me the right extracted watermark :( and in this work I tried with a binary image from the beginning, but I actually need to convert a color watermark from RGB to decimal then to binary so I can use it. and the issue I got too is when I will have an extracted watermark how to reconverted from binary to decimal then RGB!! thank you in advance

This is th original binary watermark (left)  and the result after extraction (right). I expect to have an extracted watermark as the original one.

[image]    [image]

Comment: I suggest providing images of what you use it for and what you get, with possibly some explanation of the differences with respect to expectations (if necessary).

Comment: shouldn't `[m n]=size(ca2);` be `[m,n]=size(ca2);`

Comment: @chiliNUT, commas are optional in MATLAB in this context.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, here I edit the post and I gave the images.

Comment: I'm not even close to understanding what you want this code to do. One note though: you say `L=zeros(4);` but then you explicitly assign to `L` a matrix of size `[blocksize-1, blocksize-1]`, where `blocksize` is dynamically computed from the input, so it's possible that `blocksize-1` is not 4, and then `L` might not have the size you expect it to have (and since you compare `U(2,1)` and `U(3,1)`, I suspect it would make a difference if your `U` had different size as expected). Could this be a problem?

Comment: No in all the case `L` is a matrix size[4 4] because I started my loop with 1 : `for k=1:32 for j=1:32`   but I'm using images size in such a way I will always have ` blocksize=4`  so my ` U`  will have the same size